# Query with a sum in elasticsearch 2.3.5

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm indexing documents like this into elasticsearch:

```
{
 ...
 "creationTime": x,
 "cache":
  {
   ...
   "cacheTime": y,
   ...
  }
}
```

I need to build a query that returns all expired documents, so the condition is:
x + y <= now

Can anyone help me to build this query?